# What is default value of context (last parameter) in Backbone.js "on" function?

Tags: backbone.js

I could never really figure out what the 3rd parameter in backbone.js's `.on()` function does (supposed to context):

```
this.model.on('change', this.doStuff, context);
```

According to: [Backbone.js on(), what does the last this refer to?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13415138/backbone-js-on-what-does-the-last-this-refer-to) it seems that it sets the value of `this` inside 
Can somebody give an example of that context should be. I usually use `on` without context and it seems to reference the view `this`, but once in a while it reference something else (which I cannot figure out).

So what's Backbone's logic for setting `context` by default? And when would you ever want `this` NOT to refer to the view? And is there any way to make it ALWAYS reference the View without specifying `this` as the context parameter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have a look at the [`on` source](http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-15) you'll see what the default `context` is:

```
on: function(name, callback, context) {
  //...
  events.push({callback: callback, context: context, ctx: context || this});
  //...
},
```

So the default `context` is whatever object `on` was called on: `ctx: context || this`. So if you just say:

```
model.on('event', this.callback);
```

Then `this` will be `model` inside `callback` when it gets called. If you want `this` to be the view then you say so:

```
// Inside a view...
model.on('event', this.callback, this);
```

or you make `callback` a bound function using [`_.bind`](http://underscorejs.org/#bind), [`_.bindAll`](http://underscorejs.org/#bindAll), [`Function#bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind), [`$.proxy`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/), etc.

Why would you want to specify a `context`? Well, inside a callback that is a method on a view you'll probably want `this` to be the view and there's no way for `on` to know what the view is when you call `on`: you can't unroll the stack to find out what `this` is somewhere up the call chain and even if you could, you wouldn't know where to stop. So using the `x` in `x.on(...)` is about the only reasonable default and if you want something else, you can easily say so.